# iPhone, SBJSON error

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, parsing

I'm using SBJson Parser
[this one](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)

I've this JSON value, it's a valid JSON, but still I get this error

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x63726a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"


{
"Account": {
    "LoginName": "My Name",
    "Name": "My Name"
},
"UseInvoiceAddressAsDeliveryAddress": "true",
"InvoiceAddress": {
    "Zip": "16444",
    "CountryId": "1",
    "City": "SSSS",
    "Line2": "8",
    "Line1": "Street 4"
},
"Phone": "12345678",
"FirstName": "My",
"LastName": "Name",
"Email": "sample@example.com",
"CellPhone": "234254233"
}
```

Here's my code, I think I get this JSON error, because I'm not specifying any content type, I'm doing this but still it doesn't work

```
    SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString *jsonConvertedObj = [writer stringWithObject:customerObject];
NSLog(@"The converted JSON String .... %@",jsonConvertedObj);
NSData *postData = [jsonConvertedObj dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];  
NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:postData];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setClientCertificateIdentity:identity];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request addData:myMutablePostData withFileName:@"" andContentType:@"application/json" forKey:@""];
[request startSynchronous];
```

And this is the error I receive from the server :

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The     incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.
```

Comment: May I ask what JSON library you use?

Comment: SBJsonParser https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

Comment: How do you create `myMutablePostData`?

Comment: SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
 NSString *jsonConvertedObj = [writer stringWithObject:customerObject];
 NSLog(@"The converted JSON String .... %@",jsonConvertedObj);
 NSData *postData = [jsonConvertedObj dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
 NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:postData];


I actually don't need a mutablepostdata, but that was just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it myself, this is what solved it ...

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setClientCertificateIdentity:identity];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

As suspected, I was using the wrong HTTPRequest type, and then I was not setting up the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it's possible that you have some invisible illegal character. It's also possible that this is a bug in the library you're using. So I suggest you try parsing it with a differnt library. If there's something wrong with the JSON you should get a similar error with the other library. If the other library parses your JSON without problems you should probably file a bug report for SBJSON.

I use [JSONKit](https://github.com/JimRoepcke/JSONKit) and it's always worked great for me and it's really easy to use.

Comment: NO, I think I get this error because I'm not setting ContentType. I'm doing this 

 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
 [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setClientCertificateIdentity:identity];
 [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
 [request addData:myMutablePostData withFileName:@"" andContentType:@"application/json" forKey:@""];
 [request startSynchronous];

Comment: the error from the server

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding.

Answer (score 0):

From what you pasted it's looking like there are some newline chars before your JSON starts. If this is actually the case, it could be why you're getting that error.

Comment: I've updated my post, it's due to the content type, please tell me how could I resolve this issue.

Comment: Donito, still seems like there's something wrong with the JSON you're sending. Are you wrapping something around your JSON string? Could you paste the exact JSON string you're sending? And could you please confirm that there are no newlines before the JSON string? I'm looking at your most recent comment on Erik B's answer and it's confirming that there's something wrong with the JSON string you're sending.

Comment: The JSON String mentioned in the original post is the one I'm sending. I've tested the same JSON String directly on the server and it works fine, but sending it through iPhone has issues..